# Prevent status bar NSPopover from activating main window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nspopover

I'm implementing an `NSPopover` and having it appear in the status bar by setting it as a custom view. I've set its behavior to Transient, and also added a global event monitor so that when any other application gets focus, the `NSPopover` goes away.

This is working fairly well but the only problem I'm running into is that click on the popover brings to focus the main window of the application. If I put the window on one space and view the popover on another space and interact with the popover, I get thrown back to the space with the main window and it gets focused. Is there a way to prevent this? Perhaps allow interaction with the popover without activating the application?

Comment: You could try setting your main window or the `positioningWindow` of the `NSPopover` to have the `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces` collection behavior. This would at least eliminate the space-switching problem. As for the app activation issue, you might need to make your popover window have the `NSBorderlessWindowMask`.